# Custom OpenIddictApplication field always returns null

Tags: openiddict

I am using OpenIDDict and extending OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication to include my own custom field:

```
public class TenantApplication : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication<long, TenantAuthorization, TenantToken> {
    public long? TenantID { get; set; }
}
public class TenantAuthorization : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreAuthorization<long, TenantApplication, TenantToken> { }
public class TenantScope : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreScope<long> { }
public class TenantToken : OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreToken<long, TenantApplication, TenantAuthorization> { }
```

I register under AddDbContext:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
options.UseOpenIddict<TenantApplication, TenantAuthorization, TenantScope, TenantToken, long>();
```

});

and also under AddCore:

```
    // Register the OpenIddict core components.
.AddCore(options =>
            options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                   .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
                   .ReplaceDefaultEntities<TenantApplication, TenantAuthorization, TenantScope, TenantToken, long>();
    options.UseQuartz();
})
```

In my Worker, I create the application record if it doesn't exist, but TenantID is always inserted with null:

```
if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("postman", cancellationToken) is null)
        {
            await manager.CreateAsync(new TokenOpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                TenantID = 2,
                ClientId = "postman",
                ClientSecret = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207",
                DisplayName = "My client application",
                Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
                }
            });
```

Similarly, manager.FindByClientIdAsync also returns the Application instance with a null TenantID (after I manually set it in the db). What step am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out on my own by diving into the `OpenIDDict` source code. In order to extend the Application fields, I extended `OpenIddictApplicationManager` and `OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplicationStore`. `OpenIddictApplicationManager` has a `PopulateAsync` method which converts a `OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor` to an Application instance. You need to override this method so that your custom Application fields will be set.

When initializing everything in `Program.cs` you also need to add your custom store and replace the application manager.

```
options.AddApplicationStore<TenantOpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplicationStore>();
options.ReplaceApplicationManager<TenantOpenIddictApplicationManager>();
```

Maybe there is a better way of doing this, but this worked for me. It would be nice if there was some more easier to find examples with more complex scenarios.

Comment: Hey Tyler, did you have to extend the OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor as well to set the custom fields using the SetPropertiesAsync method?

Comment: How did you override in the Manager and Store classes?